# Karate : How to extract variable from URL generated in feature in karate framework

Tags: karate

NEW TO KARATE FRAMEWORK - GUIDE WHat to refer to achieve below - documentation is vast so pointers would be appreciable

I got Location url as below
http://example.com/sdk?callback&code=3jPqg4SlD3ZF0ud58zbWuuqAD6s&iss=TEST%2Fauth%2Foauth2%2Frealms%2Froot%2Frealms%2Fhlclients&client_id=ProductApplicationSPA

- def location = responseHeaders['Location'][0]
- print location

Now i want to extract only code = 3jPqg4SlD3ZF0ud58zbWuuqAD6s and use it as a header in another API call.

Please guide how to achieve it in Karate

Normally i did as below but i want to achieve it in Karate framework
String currentURL = driver.getCurrentUrl();
String authCode = currentURL.substring(currentURL.indexOf("code=") + 5, currentURL.indexOf("&"));

Thanks

Comment: SOLUTION : Common.feature
   * def getQueryParam =
    """
    function (param, uri) {
      name = param.replace(/[\[\]]/g, '\\$&');
      var regex = new RegExp('[?&]' + name + '(=([^&#]*)|&|#|$)'),
          results = regex.exec(uri);
      if (!results) return null;
      if (!results[2]) return '';
      return decodeURIComponent(results[2].replace(/\+/g, ' '));
    }
    """
 
 Scenario : 
     * karate.log(util.getQueryParam('code',location))
 
 re-use code elsewhere
  * def code = util.getQueryParam('code', url)